# Busy Dialog not showing during server requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, sapui5

I'm working on a UI5 application. I want to block UI form users during ajax requests. I added the following code:

```js
var dialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog({
  text: this.languageModel.getModelProperty("BUSY_DIALOG_FETCHING_DATA"),
  title : this.languageModel.getModelProperty("BUSY_DIALOG_WAIT")
});
var that = this;
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
    dialog = (dialog) ? dialog : new sap.m.BusyDialog({
      text : that.languageModel.getModelProperty("BUSY_DIALOG_FETCHING_DATA"),
      title : that.languageModel.getModelProperty("BUSY_DIALOG_WAIT")
    });
    dialog.open();
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log("close");
    dialog.close();
  }
});
```

In console, I get good results, and while debugging I can see dialogs, but in normal mode (without any breakpoints) the busy dialogs don't appear at all. Any clue?

Comment: It's due to synchronous requests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61573982/5846045. Give the browser time to update the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the busy indicator?

```
var oController = this;
oController.getView().setBusy(true);
$.ajax({
    //your ajax call here, 
    success: function(data) {
        //do whatever needs to be done after success;
        oController.getView().setBusy(false);
    },
    error: function(...) {
        oController.getView().setBusy(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably sending some requests synchronously so that the browser wasn't able to update the DOM <sup>[1]</sup> while trying to open the dialog.

- When calling low-level APIs (such as `jQuery.ajax()`):

  - **NEVER** set `async: false`.
  - **NEVER** call `jQuery.sap.sjax` as it's deprecated due to sending sync XHRs only.
- Migrate to asynchronous APIs. Follow the best-practices mentioned below:

  - [Is Your Application Ready for Asynchronous Loading?](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/493a15aa978d4fe9a67ea9407166eb01)
  - [Use Asynchronous Loading](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/676b636446c94eada183b1218a824717)
  - In case of OData: **DO NOT** use the **deprecated** `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`! It sends many requests with sync XHRs by default. Consider using `v2.ODataModel` or `v4.ODataModel` depending on the OData service.

---

<sup>[1] Sending requests synchronously **blocks** the *main*-thread (which is the *UI*-thread at the same time) of the browser which results in a bad UX. It's also [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) by the web platform.</sup>