# Sapui5 ODATA Busy Indicator Dialog don't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, odata, sapui5

I have an issue with my code, i need to show a busy dialog when i click on "save", but it doesn't show i don't know why, i searched for 5 days and nothing helped me, i tried with async post, with delayed call and other things to make this work.

[image: Button]

On the image when i click on the button "Guardar", after that i need to show a busy dialog when the comunication to the server starts, the code what i have is the next:

```
onSaveRaw: function(oEvent) {

        var that = this;
        var ILgort = this.byId("sAlmacen_id").getValue();
        var IWerks = this.byId("sCentro_id").getValue();
        var IFechaoper = this.byId("sDate_id").getValue();
        var RecTemm = this.byId("sTemm_id").getValue();
        var RecTemt = this.byId("sTemt_id").getValue();
        var RecDeno = this.byId("sDeno_id").getValue();
        var RecPorc = this.byId("sPorc_id").getValue();
        var RecPres = this.byId("sPres_id").getValue();
        var RecHume = this.getView().byId("_select0").getSelectedKey();
        var RecAgua = this.getView().byId("_select1").getSelectedKey();

        if (this.validarCampoRequerido(ILgort)) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.validarCampoRequerido(IWerks)) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.validarCampoRequerido(IFechaoper)) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.validarCampoRequerido(RecTemm)) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.validarCampoRequerido(RecTemt)) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.validarCampoRequerido(RecDeno)) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.validarCampoRequerido(RecPorc)) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.validarCampoRequerido(RecPres)) {
            return;
        }
        //Creación del catalogo de datos del formulario.
        var dialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
            title: "Confirmación",
            type: "Message",
            state: "Warning",
            content: new sap.m.Text({
                text: "Se generará el documento de inventario. ¿Desea continuar?"
            }),
            beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Guardar",
                press: function() {
                    var oData = {
                        "ILgort": ILgort,
                        "IWerks": IWerks,
                        "IFechainv": IFechaoper,
                        "ICharact010": RecTemm,
                        "ICharact020": RecTemt,
                        "ICharact030": RecDeno,
                        "ICharact040": RecPorc,
                        "ICharact050": RecPres,
                        "ICharact080": RecHume,
                        "ICharact090": RecAgua
                    };
                    //console.log(oData);var _this = this;

                    //Se crea instancia del servicio
                    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/XXXXXXXXX/");
                    var oGlobalBusyDialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
                    oGlobalBusyDialog.open();
                    oModel.create("/LECTURATANQUESet", oData, null, function(oResponse) {
                        sap.m.MessageBox.alert(oResponse.Message, {
                            title: "Exito",
                            textDirection: sap.ui.core.TextDirection.Inherit,
                            onClose: function() {
                                that.onRefresh();
                                that._navBack();
                            }
                        });
                    }, function(oError) {
                        var oNum = oError.response.statusCode;
                        if (oNum == "500") {
                            sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Error, Sesión Finalizada por tiempo de Conexión.", {
                                title: "Error",
                                textDirection: sap.ui.core.TextDirection.Inherit,
                                onClose: function() {}

                            });

                        } else if (oNum == "504") {
                            sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Error de gateway, vuelva a intentar por favor.", {
                                title: "Error",
                                textDirection: sap.ui.core.TextDirection.Inherit,
                                onClose: function() {}

                            });

                        } else {

                            var oMsg = $(oError.response.body).find("message").first().text();
                            sap.m.MessageBox.alert(oMsg, {
                                title: "Error",
                                textDirection: sap.ui.core.TextDirection.Inherit,
                                onClose: function() {}

                            });

                        }

                    });
                    oGlobalBusyDialog.close();
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }),
            endButton: new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Cancelar",
                press: function() {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }),
            afterClose: function() {

            }
        });
        dialog.open();

    }
```

If someone can give me any tip I'll be very greatful.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61573982/5846045. The main issue is that the app is relying on the deprecated `ODataModel` which mainly uses sync XHR, thus freezing the UI thread preventing the dialog to show up during the request. Use `v2.ODataModel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `oGlobalBusyDialog.close();` inside the success and error callbacks of the `create` function. So, when ever the `create` function completes (either a success or error) you will close the busy dialog.

Also, you've to delete the `oGlobalBusyDialog.close();` in the second last line of the `press` event handler.

**EDIT** (Updating how to use `create`, after re-reading the docs)

Use `create` like this

```
oModel.create("/LECTURATANQUESet",
    oData, {
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallbak
    }
)
```

Comment: i gonna try! :)

Comment: Also, as per the [SAPUI5 docs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#create), the `create` function takes success callback as 5th parameter and error as 6th. Could you change and try that as well?

Comment: trying changing the method? how?

Comment: Thanks for the example, i will try this now, i gonna reply you if works :)

Comment: Well, doesn't work, is the same, it keeps freeze and later doesn't show the message dialog with the success or error... :/

Comment: I don't think I can be of anymore help, without a minimal working sample to debug. If you can provide one, I can look at it and try helping.

Comment: Thx for your help anyway :)

Comment: I misread the docs. Try the format that I've given in the latest answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong BusyIndicator. Try this out:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/BusyIndicator"
],
function (BusyIndicator) {
    BusyIndicator.show();
    //...
    BusyIndicator.hide();
});
```

Comment: If you do that, the indicator will be shown and **immediately** hidden. The call to `hide()` has to happen in the asynchronous callback.

Comment: @Marc absolutely, it seems obvious for me, that's why I just simplified the usage example... Then I would also add that BusyIndicator should be hidden when any async error happens, otherwise it will lock whole page.

Comment: Well if you look at Sarco's code it's not so obvious ;) His `hide` is not in the callback.

Comment: @Sarco well, which version of sapui5 are you using?

Comment: 1.28.44, that version.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem recently also. The Create function of sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel, when executed (synchronously), freezes the browser and prevents the slower busy indicator from showing.

I solved it by activating the async mode of the function (it is executed synchronously by default):

```
oModel.create("/LECTURATANQUESet",
oData, {
    success: successCallback,
    error: errorCallbak, 
    async: true
}
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel%23methods/Summary

However, this should be done with some considerations: "Whether the request should be done asynchronously. Default: false Please be advised that this feature is officially unsupported as using asynchronous requests can lead to data inconsistencies if the application does not make sure that the request was completed before continuing to work with the data."

Just add the solution here to somebody that needs xD!

Comment: Hi jaop! Thank you for your contribution to the UI5 Q&As! The main issue is, as you already noted, that the `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` relies heavily on sync XHR by default which is the reason why that model is deprecated. Please consider using `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` instead. Let me know if you encounter issues by that!